# What is the best way to write trigger for two linked database in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

What is the best method to write a database trigger if you are updating the table in target database while noticing the change in source database table.

For example: If I have source-database.source-table and target-database.target-table. I wants to insert an entry into target-database.target-table while there is a change in source-database.source-table. Can I write something like this.

**Method 1: Write trigger on target database:**

```
create or replace trigger "target-database"."target-trigger"
after update on source-database.source-table@source-dblink
for each row
where (:new.some-col <> :old.some-col)
begin
insert into target-database.target-table ("col1","col2","col3")
values
("value1","value2","value3")
end;
```

**Method 2: Write trigger on source database**

```
create or replace trigger "source-database"."source-trigger"
after update on source-database.source-table
for each row
where (:new.some-col <> :old.some-col)
begin
insert into target-database.target-table@target-dblink ("col1","col2","col3")
values
("value1","value2","value3")
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you were going to create a trigger to implement replication, the trigger would need to exist on the source database.  It's not syntactically valid to create the trigger on the target database.  If you did create the trigger on the source database, you'd need to use the database link to reference the target table, you wouldn't have a database link in the `ON <<table name>>` clause.

However, you really, really don't want to use a trigger to implement replication.  Oracle provides a host of tools to implement replication-- materialized views, Streams, Golden Gate, etc.  You really, really want to be using one of those solutions.

- If you use a trigger to replicate data, you're significantly reducing the availability of the system.  The transaction against the source table can only succeed if the remote database is up and running and if the network link between the two is up.  That forces the two systems to be tightly coupled-- you can't take one site down for maintenance without affecting the other.
- If you use a trigger to replicate data, you're significantly affecting the performance of the system.  The transaction against the source table now has to involve a two-phase commit with the remote database.  That's going to involve multiple network round-trips and will generally be rather slow (certainly slow compared to a local transaction).

A real replication solution, on the other hand, will replicate the data asynchronously with little or no effect on the performance of transactions.  If both systems are up, the data will replicate after a very short lag.  If the destination system is unavailable, local transactions will still succeed and the data will replicate when the destination system comes back up.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, I would rather start in source DB and do something like:

```
create or replace trigger "source-database"."source-trigger"
after update on source-database.source-table
for each row
where (:new.some-col <> :old.some-col)
begin
    insert into target-database.target-table@target-dblink ("col1","col2","col3")
    values ("value1","value2","value3");
end;   
/
```

There is no reference to a DB link before the insert, which is preferable IMHO.